# Codeigniter - Sort data from three tables

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have three tables as below. Primary keys are highlighted and foreign keys in italic

1. projecttasks 
   [ **projecttasksid**, *projectstructureid*, *assignto*, taskname ]
2. projectstructure
   [**projectstructureid**, *projectid*, structurename]
3. projects
   [**projectid**, projectname]

I can get projecttasks comparing 'assignto' and userID form the session array.
So that I am getting tasks assigned to the logged in user.

What is the best way to get 'projectstructure' and 'projects' only for the logged in user / from 'assignto' field in Codeigniter way.

I want to write,
get_structures() and
get_projects()

Code,

```
$user_id    = $this->session->userdata('userID');

$data       = array('main_content'  => 'view_project_tasks_page',
                    'tasks'     => $this->projects->get_project_tasks($user_id),
                    'structures'    => $this->projects->get_structures(),
                    'projects'  => $this->projects->get_projects()  );

$this->load->view('template', $data);
```

Model - get_project_tasks($user_id)

```
function get_project_tasks($user_id)
{
$rules = array('assignto'   => $user_id );

$this->db->select()->from('projecttasks')->where($rules);
$sql_stmt = $this->db->get();
return $sql_stmt->result();
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us what you have tried?

Comment: post your query you have done

Comment: I have added coding above please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you search is a simple Right Join

In "CodeIgniter way" it should look something like this (not tested)

```
function get_structures($user_id) {
    $rules = array('projecttasks.assignto' => $user_id );

    $this->db->select('projectstructure.*')
        ->from('projectstructure')
        ->join('projecttasks', 'projecttasks.projectstructureid = projectstructure.projectstructureid')
        ->where($rules);

    $sql_stmt = $this->db->get();
    return $sql_stmt->result();
}

function get_projects($user_id) {
    $rules = array('projecttasks.assignto' => $user_id );

    $this->db->select('project.*')
        ->from('projectstructure')
        ->join('projecttasks', 'projecttasks.projectstructureid = projectstructure.projectstructureid')
        ->join('project', 'projecttasks.projectid = project.projectid')
        ->where($rules);

    $sql_stmt = $this->db->get();
    return $sql_stmt->result();
}
```

Comment: Yes it is simple but wanted ti know in the Codeigniter way and thanks for this.